# Widget dragging images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna  know if this is possible using javascript to drag and anchor an image from widget to any part of the page (over any content). That should stay over same content on page resize or scrolling.?

Comment: How do you define widget? Is that your code? If so, you should be able to add event listeners to the images in it, so that you can adjust their top/left position with mousemove (and those images have position:absolute)

Comment: The widget I define it as a div, his position is somewhere on right corner, and fixed. Is my code. I am not really proffessional to know many things... can you write some codes javascript about this widget to take images from him and place them everywhere on the page ?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. its possible to drag and drop an image from widget.. This [tutorial](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) may help you...

Comment: Then try this [link](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?page=dragDrop)... The content under Custom drag and drop script  may help you...